# Why am I getting Segmentation Fault (Core dumped)

Tags: c

Sorry for the noob question, but I haven't found anyone on the forums who seemed to have a similar problem (or I didn't understand them enough)

I'm pretty new to C and got a challenge to make a program that fills a 2D array using a function and pointers, so far my code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int testef(int i, int j, int **teste){

    if(i == 2){
        return 0;
    }
    if(j == 2){
        return testef(i+1,0,&teste);
    }
    else{
        printf("Value[%d][%d]: ",i,j);
        scanf("%d",&teste[i][j]);
        return testef(i,j+1,&teste);
    }
}

int main() {
    int teste[2][2];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    testef(i,j,&teste[2][2]);


    return 0;
}
```

I could easily do it inside the main function with a for loop, but the challenge was to have a function do it with pointer. But for some reason, once the compiler reaches the line to call the function, I get a Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) error. Any ideas why? I've tried quite a few forums but haven't found anyone having a similar problem.

Comment: Hint: Where did you allocate the values `teste` supposedly points to? Also, side-note: `return testef(i,j++,teste);` isn't doing what you think; `j++` evaluates to the *original* value of `j`, not the incremented value (`j` is incremented afterwards, but the recursive call receives the original value, and you never use `j` after that so the increment effectively did nothing). You probably wanted `return testef(i, ++j,teste);`, so the incremented value is passed.

Comment: You should be getting a warning about argument type mismatch.

Comment: `testef()` expects an argument of type `int **`, but you're giving it `int **[2][2]`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Or `return testef(i, j+1, teste);`. No need to use an increment operator if the variable is not used afterward.

Comment: `cdecl> explain int ** teste[2][2]
declare teste as array 2 of array 2 of pointer to pointer to int
cdecl> explain int **teste 
declare teste as pointer to pointer to int`  These 2 things are not the same

Comment: meaning of your declaration  `int ** teste[2][2]` can also be checked from [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+**teste%5B2%5D%5B2%5D)

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here seems to be that you mistakenly tried to use *both* double pointers and a 2D array at the same time, when you really only wanted a 2D array (which could be implemented multiple ways, but an explicit stack allocated 2D array is simpler than a dynamically allocated array of arrays).

To fix the most basic issues:

1. Make the original (`main`) `teste` just `int teste[2][2];`, not `*`s for pointers, to get a block allocated 2D array.
2. Change `testef` to receive `int teste[2][2]` (the first dimension needed not be specified, but the second is necessary), matching what it will receive
3. `scanf` should be `scanf("%d", &teste[i][j]);` (so it get the address to store to, not an `int` value that it tries to interpret as an `int*`)
4. Change `return testef(i,j++,teste);` to `return testef(i,j+1,teste);` so you actually pass an incremented value (passing `j++` passed the unmodified `j` to the recursive call, and incremented `j` later).
5. Fix (in an unspecified way since the goal is unclear here) `testef` so it doesn't *always* recurse; as is, it would recurse forever (`j` would go from `0` to `2` and back to `0` until you hit a stack overflow). You need to ensure it will eventually hit a terminal case and return back to `main` (logically, the correct answer seems to be "after it's initialized all four elements").

Changes 1-3 are a package deal which remove the need for explicit dynamic allocation entirely. You could use `int**` with a few explicit `malloc` and `free` calls, but given the hardcoded array dimensions, it's simpler and more efficient to go with the block 2D array.

Comment: I did all the changes you mentioned and edited the code on the question. Now my code returns the same error, but after the first scanf() instead of when the line where I call the function

Comment: @GustavoAraújo: I missed one thing; you shouldn't be passing `&teste` in the recursive calls, just `teste`; you received the right type, you just pass it on, you don't pass along the address of it (which would add another layer of indirection).